# Macro - Create List - Count - Sort

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a spreadsheet where I import 100,000 rows of data, split it out into separate words then consolidate the list (I’ve reduced the sample size for ease)
The macro takes all the separated words and puts these into a list and counts the number of times each unique word turns up in the full selection of data.

This has run for several large sized data sets but now I’m getting an error and a small sample and can’t see how to fix this. I have attached an example data set and also my code.

I have tried removing "_" & "-" thinking characters might be stopping the macro, but this did not help.

Data is split from an e-mail that is on tab "SCRUB" "B3:B" and text to col listed "SCRUB" "C3:XFD"
The code should take the individual words in "SCRUB" "C3:XFD" and list "LIST" "A2:A" & count "LIST" "B2:B". Then sort by "LIST" "B"

Run-time error **'1004': Unable to get the CountIf property of the WorksheetFunction class**

Below is the code:

```
Sub ListCreate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim s As Worksheet, ss As Worksheet
Set s = Sheets("SCRUB")
Set ss = Sheets("List")
ss.Range("A2:A650000").ClearContents
lr = s.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
counter = 2
For i = 3 To lr
    For j = 3 To s.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
         txt = s.Cells(i, j)
           If txt <> "" And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ss.Range("A:A"), txt) = 0 Then
            ss.Range("A" & counter).Value = txt
            ss.Range("B" & counter).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(s.Range("C:XFD"), txt)
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i
    lr = ss.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ss.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ss.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ss.Range("B2:B" & lr), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ss.Sort
        .SetRange ss.Range("A1:B" & lr)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub

'Clean the string of text
Function cleanString(text As String) As String
    Dim output As String
    Dim c 'since char type does not exist in vba, we have to use variant type.
    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        c = Mid(text, i, 1) 'Select the character at the i position
        If (c >= "a" And c <= "z") Or (c >= "0" And c <= "9") Or (c >= "A" And c <= "Z") Then
            output = output & c 'add the character to your output.
        Else
            output = output & " " 'add the replacement character (space) to your output
        End If
    Next
    cleanString = output
End Function
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Sample of 10 lines of e-mails which the macro breaks on, with whitespace (Hi denotes new cell)

```
Hi Team,

 

Please advise if the trades below need to be settled as Gross or Net.

 

Thanks

 

 

CustomerBroker IDBroker/BicTrade_dateValue_DateBuy_CcyBuy_AmountSell_CcySell_AmountFx_Exch_rateClient_Ref

00000000AAAAAAAA00000000000EUR2,224.00TRY16,548.200.4400000000000

00000000AAAAAAAA000000000000GBP200,082.99SEK286,619.000.690000000000




Hi Team,

 

Please advise if the trades below need to be settled as Gross or Net.

 

Thanks

 

 

CustomerBroker IDBroker/BicTrade_dateValue_DateBuy_CcyBuy_AmountSell_CcySell_AmountFx_Exch_rateClient_Ref

00000000AAAAAAAA0000000000000000NOK33,202.00EUR3,183.2510.4300000000000

00000000AAAAAAAA0000000000000000SEK571,826.00EUR53,478.6910.690000000000

00000000AAAAAAAA0000000000000000SEK1,727,152.00EUR161,527.8610.6900000000000

00000000AAAAAAAA0000000000000000EUR18.70SEK200.0010.69000000000000

00000000AAAAAAAA0000000000000000EUR55,083.45SEK588,985.0010.6900000000000

00000000AAAAAAAA000000000000EUR18.7SEK200.0010.11000000000000





Hi Good day.

 

Following up on the below request.

 

Thank you.

Hi

++ back up attached 

 

Name 

 
Hi Name.



The checklist is included in the 'blaht Account Forms' section on the website.



Please find attached a copy of the checklist.






-----Original Message-----



 

Hi Good Afternoon 

 

We need to urgently organize a call with yourselves this afternoon to confirm some payment details.

 

The account in question is TYT0000000 and it concerns a trade TD 13/06/2022 SD 15/06/2022 

 

We need to confirm the bank details this afternoon.

 

Can you kindly confirm a time today in which we may call you.

 

 

Kind regards,

 


 





.

 

 

 

 

 
 Hi Team,

 

Please advise on trade below as the holdings are in Germany but trade is instructed to settle in Clearstream. Please review and advise

 

Thanks

 

 

Order IdOrder TypeClient ReferenceCustody Position StatusDiary Remark IndicatorCancellation StatusDepository ReferenceStatusSecurity Account IdTrade DateSettlement DateSecurity NumberNet Settlement AmountQuantityTrade CurrencyTransaction Type

0000008Delivery Versus Payment000000000ASDNoCancellation Not Initiated To Be Authorised0000:DAA INV.SCV-EUROP CORP.SUST.B24/06/202228/06/2022DE000YYY0GU5:AAAAA-HAN HY 5,5% 16-26.09.23EUR : 1,000,407.26FAMT : 20,300,000.000000000000000EURSettlement Deliver



 



 

.

 

Hi 

Thank you for being so tenacious and bringing this matter to resolution, .  Well done !  Appreciate the update.  

 


Hi 

Anytime!

 



 



Hi human, 

 

Please find attached COAS call back for your approval. 

 

 

Thank you
```

Comment: Could you paste some sample data please - _Edit_ button is just below the tags at the bottom of your question.  [This](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) will help format your data for posting.  Afraid you can't attach files on here.

Comment: What is the value of `txt ` when it fails? ¿Maybe something like `=,>,<` ?

Comment: It's hard to add a sample, as it works on individual, but if there is a larger set it fails. I will  try to add the 10 samples

Comment: Are you running that `cleanString` method on your data before doing any processing?